# Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n \ln(n)}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm a student, solving convergence problems today.

I can show that the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln{n}}$ diverges by **integral test** ($F(x) = \ln{(\ln{x})}, F'(x) = f(x) =  \frac{1}{x \ln{x}}$)

But I don't have any idea for the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n \ln(n)}$

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this does converge. In alternating series', as long as the absolute value of the numbers get closer to zero, it converges. 1/ln(n)n always get closer to 0 as n gets closer to infinity.

Comment: $a_n \to 0$ is not enough, we need the monotonity of $|a_n|$ as well.

Comment: Yes, if $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=-\frac{1}{2^n}$ then $a_n\to 0$ alternates, but $\sum a_n$ diverges. You need that $|a_n|$ is monotonic decreasing.

Answer (score 3):

The [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) immediately implies that the series converges.